# Mysql: How to make a column in a materialized view the primary key

Tags: mysql

I'm writing a query to create a table based on a materialized view. something like

"
Create tableView AS
SELECT table1.column1,
table2.column4,
table3.column7
FROM
...
"

How do I change this query so that table1.column1 becomes the primary key of this table?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with

```
CREATE TABLE tableView (PRIMARY KEY (column1)) 
SELECT table1.column1, table2.column4, table3.column7 FROM ...
```

see [CREATE TABLE ... SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-select.html)

> CREATE TABLE ... SELECT does not automatically create any indexes for
>   you. This is done intentionally to make the statement as flexible as
>   possible. **If you want to have indexes in the created table, you should
>   specify these before the SELECT statement:**
>
> mysql> CREATE TABLE bar (UNIQUE (n)) SELECT n FROM foo;

Emphasis by me, see a [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cad1a/1) where the original table has no key.